# Java nested and / or child classes

Tags: java

I was wondering what best practices were in java when running a nested class - im thinking of running an rmi server that would be created upon the instanciation of the parent class so, say

```
class foo() [the 'parent']
constructor for foo() - instanciates rmifoo()
```

this get a bit painful when you want to call a method from rmifoo() back in the 'parent' class (you cant simply import the class, because of rmi). one way is of course to make rmifoo() an actual child class, and then be able to access methods in the parent, but this seems needlessly OTT (esp because then, presumably you need to make the parent abstract, etc etc and that really complicates a lot of other functionality).

I was wonder what the best practise is in terms of setting up a system like this, so one can call methods back in the foo() class from within its server ie. rmifoo()

*********update*******

Code (as im thinking of it currently) would be somethine like:

A.java:

```
public class A {
B aBinstance;

  public fooParent() {
  [do something..]
  }
}
```

B.Java

```
public class B { 
  public fooChild() {
   [super].fooParent()  (super wont work...?)
  }
```

}

Comment: Your updated example doesn't make any sense to me.  I cannot even figure out if you are trying to express a containment (has-a) or subtyping (is-a) relationship.

Comment: oh, its a bit convoluted because of the RMI - i gave up on this avenue and just rejigged it completely differently, made the code much cleaner.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
public class A {

   private B b;

   public A() {
      b = new b(this);
   }

   public aMethodInA() {
      //stuff goes here
   }
}


public class B {

   private A a;

   public B(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   public aMethodCallingMethodsInTheObjectThatInstantiatedMe() {
      a.aMethodInA();
   }
}
```

This is doable and very useful in some cases, but you end up with these circular references, and that is something that you usually want to avoid.
Think about why you need to call the class A from B. Maybe there is a way to split your problem into three classes and break your circular references that way.

Answer (score 0):

If `rmifoo` is an inner class inside `foo`, then it can directly access the methods in `foo`.

[EDIT]: This applies only if `rmifoo` class is not a `static inner class`, in which case it will be only abel to access static methods in foo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really asking whether or not is a good idea to use Java nested classes to implement a containment relationship in your application's (conceptual) object model; as in ...

```
public class A {
    public class B { 
        public A getParent() {
            return A.this;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm inclined to think that it is not a good idea:

- This approach breaks down if the relationship is recursive.  For example, if an A can contain a B and B can contain an A, you cannot *both* make B a nested class of A, *and* A a nested class of B.
- The approach does not allow an instance of B to be created independently of an A, or to be moved from one A instance to another.

Also, while this approach handles the child-to-parent navigation, it does not provide parent-to-children navigation.  You'd still have to implement that explicitly; e.g. with an attribute like

```
 private List<B> children;
```

in the A class.

I think it is generally better (e.g. more flexible) to implement A and B as separate non-nested classes and use explicit `parent` and/or `chidren` attributes (as required) to represent the containment relationship.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, to be honest i think my question is a bit of both. 

I've updated the orig q. above to better reflect the code as i would have thought it would be cleanest. 
Im curious about the parent / child attributes you mention: are these somewhat along the lines of http://www.java-forums.org/java-tips/6296-inner-class-accessing-outer-class.html
this doesnt appear to work if the classes are in two different files though... and only nested in the sense that one is declared in another/...